# Caching a form when it is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, caching

I have quite an advanced form in my Ruby on Rails app that I have had cached for a while. The other day I realized the form showed checkboxes with pre-filled values which puzzled me until I realized the form had probably been cached while a user used it.

Since you can't really plan when a fragment is being cached it may actually be cached while the form is being used.

I really would like this form to be cached (since it is quite slow to populate) but I need it to be cached while it is empty!

I could copy-and-paste the html from the source while it is empty but that is a really ugly solution!

Any suggestions on how I can do that? The form is quite rarely changed.

Comment: Can you paste your form in the question?

Comment: Not really unfortunately, it would be quite confusing and also bit of a key feature of the website of which I don't want to keep public. I feel the question should be able to answer without it, but I may be wrong.